# JVM terminated with Exit Code 1 while accessing JFrame

Tags: eclipse, swing, jframe, java

I am using Eclipse Mars Ide on Ubuntu 15.10. When I was trying to create JFrame, Eclipse is trying to initialize design and while initializing, it suddenly stops and showing:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2f8001
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

Default JDK of System is JDK8.
BUT I have written JDK7 in eclipse.ini page 
code of eclipse.ini is

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

doing default JDK7 producing to run other Java program.

Please help to get rid of this, so that I can work on Jframe.

Answer (score 0):

For me deinstalling the 3d Vision Driver did the trick, like posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860723/java-is-shutting-down-when-creating-a-new-jframe-when-started-from-eclipse-no-e)